# Use Vesa Video Mode in Java

Tags: java

How to use Vesa Video mode in Java?

Comment: What could you *possibly* hope to accomplish by doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have java run as a full screen app, aka exclusive mode.

```
DisplayMode oldDisplayMode = myDevice.getDisplayMode();
try {
    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(myWindow);
    myDevice.setDisplayMode(newDisplayMode);
    ...
} finally {
    myDevice.setDisplayMode(oldDisplayMode);
    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}
```

You can also change the display mode. If the device supports the Vesa modes, then it may be in the list of available modes in Java.

See [Sun Tutorial - Full Screen Exclusive Mode](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html)